# How to use call a webservice and read the XML using python3?

Tags: xml, web-services, python-3.x

I have a server, which is wrote in asp.net, I would like to use a python client to call it, and it respond the XML to me. HOw can I call it and get the XML attribute from python3? Please suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If the server uses RPC, then [xmlrpc.client](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/xmlrpc.client.html) is the ticket. If it uses straight http, then [http.client](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.client.html) is what you would use.

You can then parse the xml either with one of the sincluded xml libraries, or with the excellent [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library.